# Set SettingsFlyout Direction

Tags: uwp, flyout, windows-8.1-universal

i have a "SettingsFlyout" that always display at the right side of the screen, can i set it to display at the left side? i added images that shows the close and the open state.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SettingsFlyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.settingsflyout) is displayed on the right side of your app window by default when you call the **Show** or **ShowIndependent** methods, it is by design, we can not make it display on the left side.

If you want to display your settings on the left of app window, you can try to create your own setting flyout by using the [Flyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout) or the [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup). Please also notice the Remarks part of the both controls.